# Using path parameter on API of NextJS

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I have a simple `pages/api/thumbnail.js` file with a handler:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  console.dir(req.params)
  // ...
}
```

On a pure express server, it is possible to have a "path parameter", but on NextJS I got a error 404 if a try to pass some path on my API.

Example:

> http://localhost:3000/api/thumbnail >> OK, it works

Now with a path:

> http://localhost:3000/api/thumbnail/something >> ERROR, 404 not found!

Using NextJS API is it possible to use path parameters or only *query string*?

PS. I am using Vercel, if using a rewrite is the only solution, its acceptable to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try adding three dots on the file name like this: `pages/api/thumbnail/[[...params]].js` Then you can load the params in your handler from `req.query`

Source: [optional-catch-all-api-routes in next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes#optional-catch-all-api-routes)

Comment: How to access query params in this case? i.e. if we have both path and query params?

Comment: @darKnight I am not working with next.js for a while, but I used to import `useSarchParams`, see here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params